# Check if recursive children of struct are NULL (C Language)

Tags: c, recursion, struct

How can I check if recursive children of the struct defined in my code are NULL (or empty, not used)? (I want to know if they are NULL so that I can fill them with data).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define HEIGHT 256
#define LENGTH 256

typedef struct FS FS;
typedef struct Elem Elem;

struct Elem {
  char name[256];
  char content[256];
  Elem *child[1024];
};

struct FS {
  Elem *child[1024];
};

void create(FS *fs, char path[HEIGHT][LENGTH]){

    while(i<1024){

        if(fs->child[i] == NULL){    //check if child[i] is NULL, if so I can fill it with data

            Elem *e;
            e = malloc(sizeof (Elem));
            fs->child[i] = e;
            strcpy(e->name, path[0]);
            i = 1024;
        }
        i++;
    }
}

int main(void) {

    FS *fs;
    char path[HEIGHT][LENGTH];

    create(fs, path);

    return 0;
}
```

At this line `fs->child[i] == NULL` and this line `fs->child[i] = e` it returns `Segmentation fault: 11` during Runtime. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You didn't assign a valid pointer value to `fs`. So `fs->...` is an illegal address reference.

Comment: Where do you create `fs`?

Comment: First, you need to assign valid pointer to `fs` somewhere with `malloc` & then initialize the whole thing to zeros with `memset`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FS *fs;` should be instead `FS *fs = (FS*) malloc (sizeof(FS));`. Most likely you know how to allocate a memory block but you seem as forgot it. However, don't forget to make it `free(fs);`

Comment: [Don't cast the return of `malloc`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)

Comment: @lurker so you suggest to do something like this instead `FS *fs = malloc (sizeof(FS));`?

Comment: Yes. See the link I provided.